# Interactive picture

Tags: php, css, canvas, svg

How can be done - hompeage which is a room picture, but with interactive parts, for example if you click on the picture on the wall a gallery is opened, or if you click on the TV some video is played and so on...I'm not using flash at all, but maybet it's an option, still I search for any other way to do this, I'm not even sure what exacctly should be used here, is there a way to make this using an image file or maybe some Canvas, SVG...I don't know.Any suggestions?
  Ty

Leron

Comment: Use <map>, Use Div, Position absolute, Use <video>, Use float. 101 ways to do it!

Comment: Flash would probably be best here. It's pretty much made to build stuff like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve this is using an image map:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map

Code from the article:

```
<img src="image.png" alt="alternative text" usemap="#mapname" />
<map name="mapname">
    <area shape="rect" coords="9,372,66,397" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/" />
</map>
```

You plot out the areas of the picture with co-ordinates (the door, the tv) and those become clickable.

You could then use JavaScript to display the gallery or video over the parts of the image.

Comment: Thanks, obv. it's a way to do this but I when the image is actually a background, by which I mean, it will resize with the screen do the coordinates stay the same?

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML's tag MAP/Area

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/area

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a HTML map and on click open the images/videos via Javascript, and let the user have the ability to click off the video, image, etc.

Here's a great example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp